# Getting errors while creating a new connection profile to connect VSCode with my MySQL database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, connection

My goal is to use a database inside of VSCode.
I have extensions like SQLTools and MySQL all installed.

I already managed to import the database into VSCode, however when executing a query it asks to make a new connection profile, however I always run into the same issue shown in the screenshot:

[image]

This is what I've written when creating the profile:

- hostname/connection string: localhost
- [Optional] Database Name:
- Authentication Type: SQL Login
- User name: root
- Password: *my password*
- [Optional] Display Name: *nothing*

I've also tried creating a new user through the cmd and used that username and password, however I still run into the same issue.

After entering that, the Errors appear. Sometimes there is also the Error: "mssql: Error: Error".

I've found that if I click on "Run on active connection" it executes the command just fine, but I imagine this isn't optimal long term, right?

Please explain in easy terms, as you might expect I'm a beginner, thank you.

Comment: `MySQL !== MSSQL` !!! Mysql is MySQL whereas MSSQL is SQLServer